# Is it possible to run commands in IPython with debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

Here are my actions in IPython:

```
> import my_module
> import ipdb
```

Now, my module lacks any executable code, it only declares classes. So I want to make a statement:

```
> g = my_module.Graph()
> f = open('test.osm')
> g.from_osm(f)
```

I want to put a breakpoint inside Graph.from_osm, without editing the file. I don't want to put the latter lines into the file and to do `python -m ipdb ...`. I just want to run commands and debug.

Is this possible?

**added:** I see, it's possible to

```
%run -d script_name
```

or

```
> import pdb
> pdb.run('statement')
```

but it's impossible to do `ipdb.run('statement')`, there's no `.run` in `ipdb`!

Comment: There is a `.run` in ipdb 0.8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stepping into a function in IPython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646670/stepping-into-a-function-in-ipython)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Since `IPython 3.2.2`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/f042f3fea7560afcb518a1940daa46a72fbcfa68), the `%debug` magic, if given an argument (a single line or a cell), executes it under debugger.

- It breaks before executing anything, giving you a chance to set breakpoints and/or start stepping through the code.
- And it accepts a `--breakpoint` argument that sets one more breakpoint (as a part of the command, it'll be saved in command history, saving you typing for repeated invocations).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the 'magic' commands **%debug** and / or **%pdb** in IPython can help you.

Comment: No, it's not what I look for. They both stop at an exception. I just want to watch program execution step by step.

Comment: As of `IPython 5`, `debug` stops before executing anything, allowing you to set breakpoints and/or begin stepping through the code.

Comment: IPython 6 stops at exception