# Stepping into a function in IPython

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pdb

Is there a way to step into the first line of a function in ipython. I imagine something that would look like:

```
%step foo(1, 2)
```

which runs `ipdb` and sets a breakpoint at the first line of `foo`.

If I want to do this now I have to go to the function's source code and add an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` line.

Comment: There's no function like `%step`. You can `%run -d` a whole script, but you can't do the same thing for a single statement or function call. You can manually `pdb.run("foo(1, 2)")` or `pdb.runcall(foo, 1, 2)`.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing today. I would use this all the time if it was available. Time to dig into the iPython source to see how it could be implemented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run commands in IPython with debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689378/is-it-possible-to-run-commands-in-ipython-with-debugging)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

ipdb has had support for runcall, runeval and run since 0.7, earlier this year. You can use it just like `pdb.runcall`:

```
In [1]: def foo(a, b):
   ...:     print a + b
   ...:

In [2]: import ipdb

In [3]: ipdb.runcall(foo, 1, 2)
> <ipython-input-1-2e565fd9c4a4>(2)foo()
      1 def foo(a, b):
----> 2     print a + b
      3

ipdb>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I need. Thanks for pointing out the 0.7 update, I had an older version. Having that it's probably easy to add an ipython magic which uses runcall.

Comment: Actually it turns out you don't need the external ipdb, you can just do `from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb; ipdb=Pdb()`.

Comment: Not the most elegant method. I expected a magic function for such a common need. I wonder if it's not a common need for `SciPy` users...

Answer (score 39):

The IPython magic you was asking for is now implemented with the newer versions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333421/4374441

You just have to type `%debug foo(1, 2)` then `s` to step into the function.

Comment: Six years later *to the day* from the original answer! +1 works for me.