# Step-by-step debugging with IPython

Tags: python, debugging, emacs, ipython, pdb

From what I have read, there are two ways to debug code in Python:

- With a traditional debugger such as `pdb` or `ipdb`. This supports commands such as `c` for `continue`, `n` for `step-over`, `s` for `step-into` etc.), but you don't have direct access to an IPython shell which can be extremely useful for object inspection.
- Using  **IPython** by [embedding](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) an IPython shell in your code. You can do `from IPython import embed`, and then use `embed()` in your code. When your program/script hits an `embed()` statement, you are dropped into an IPython shell. This allows the full inspection of objects and testing of Python code using all the IPython goodies. However, when using `embed()` you can't **step-by-step** through the code anymore with handy keyboard shortcuts.

Is there any way to combine the best of both worlds? I.e.

1. Be able to  **step-by-step** through your code with handy pdb/ipdb keyboard shortcuts.
2. At any such step (e.g. on a given statement), have access to a full-fledged **IPython shell**.

#### IPython debugging *as in* MATLAB:

An example of this type of "enhanced debugging" can be found  in MATLAB, where the user **always** has full access to the MATLAB engine/shell, and she can still **step-by-step** through her code, define conditional breakpoints, etc. From what I have discussed with other users, this is the debugging feature that people miss the most when moving from MATLAB to IPython.

#### IPython debugging in Emacs and other editors:

I don't want to make the question too specific, but I work mostly in Emacs, so I wonder if there is any way to bring this functionality into it. **Ideally**, Emacs (or the editor) would allow the programmer to set breakpoints anywhere on the code and communicate with the interpreter or debugger to have it stop in the location of your choice, and bring to a full IPython interpreter on that location.

Comment: pdb has `!` command that executes any python command at breakpoint

Comment: I am seeking a python debugger similar to Matlab, too! For example, I do a lot of prototyping in python shell. All variables are saved with the shell. Now I meet a problem. I hope to debug one small piece of code, with those calculated variables with the shell. However, a new debugger cannot access old variables. It is not convenient for prototyping.

Comment: For Emacs users, RealGUD has an incredibly good interface.

Comment: Thanks @Clément  I have been following the repo over the last month and I am very excited about the project :) I haven't tried it yet, but once I do (or if you do) feel free to write an answer here that maybe shows how to accomplish what's requested. For others for reference, the URL is https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr

Comment: @Clément Also, if you have any experience with RealGUD & ipdb, I tried using it as explained here https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/issues/96 without luck.

Comment: It's great that you opened a ticket :) Looks like your problem was solved, too ^^

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use IPython's [`%pdb` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pdb). Just call `%pdb` in IPython and when an error occurs, you're automatically dropped to `ipdb`. While you don't have the stepping immediately, you're in `ipdb` afterwards.

This makes debugging individual functions easy, as you can just load a file with `%load` and then run a function. You could force an error with an `assert` at the right position.

`%pdb` is a line magic. Call it as `%pdb on`, `%pdb 1`, `%pdb off` or `%pdb 0`. If called without argument it works as a toggle.

Comment: ^ This is the real answer

Comment: Is there something similar where pdb has IPython like functionality without being in IPython initially?

Comment: You can also start the program with `ipython --pdb file.py -- args` and are dropped to ipdb upon an exception. Might be worth adding to the answer.

Answer (score 122):

What about ipdb.set_trace() ? In your code :

`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

**update**: now in Python 3.7, we can write `breakpoint()`. It works the same, but it also obeys to the `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` environment variable. This feature comes from [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/).

This allows for full inspection of your code, and you have access to commands such as `c` (continue), `n` (execute next line), `s` (step into the method at point) and so on.

See the [ipdb repo](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) and [a list of commands](https://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2017/07/12/ipdb-cheat-sheet.html). [IPython](https://ipython.org/) is now called (edit: part of) [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/).

---

ps: note that an ipdb command takes precedence over python code. So in order to write `list(foo)` you'd need `print(list(foo))`, or `!list(foo)` .

Also, if you like the ipython prompt (its emacs and vim modes, history, completions,…) it's easy to get the same for your project since it's based on the [python prompt toolkit](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/).

Comment: This is the way to do it.

Comment: My answer now includes how to use `ipdb` in Emacs using `RealGUD` and `isend-mode` to do exactly what the OP asks.

Comment: Jupyter is not a replacement for IPython, but for IPython Notebook. Jupyter notebooks uses kernel in the background. For Python notebook, the kernel is usually an IPython kernel.
The [IPython project](http://ipython.readthedocs.io) continues further.

Comment: `breakpoint()` is wonderful. In PyCharm it even drops you into the PyCharm debugger. It's also a quick way to enter the PyCharm debugger from functions that were pasted into the console.

Comment: After the update I could simply set the environment variable `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=IPython.embed` and then `breakpoint()` will do the job

Answer (score 41):

## (Update on May 28, 2016) Using RealGUD in Emacs

For anyone in Emacs, [this thread](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/issues/96) shows how to accomplish everything described in the OP (and more) using

1. a new important debugger in Emacs called **RealGUD** which can operate with any debugger (including `ipdb`).
2. The Emacs package `isend-mode`.

The combination of these two packages is extremely powerful and allows one to recreate exactly the behavior described in the OP and do even more.

More info on [the wiki article](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/wiki/ipdb-notes) of RealGUD for ipdb.

---

## Original answer:

After having tried many different methods for debugging Python, including everything mentioned in this thread, one of my preferred ways of debugging Python with IPython is with embedded shells.

#### Defining a custom embedded IPython shell:

Add the following on a script to your `PYTHONPATH`, so that the method `ipsh()` becomes available.

```
import inspect

# First import the embed function
from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed
from IPython.config.loader import Config

# Configure the prompt so that I know I am in a nested (embedded) shell
cfg = Config()
prompt_config = cfg.PromptManager
prompt_config.in_template = 'N.In <\\#>: '
prompt_config.in2_template = '   .\\D.: '
prompt_config.out_template = 'N.Out<\\#>: '

# Messages displayed when I drop into and exit the shell.
banner_msg = ("\n**Nested Interpreter:\n"
"Hit Ctrl-D to exit interpreter and continue program.\n"
"Note that if you use %kill_embedded, you can fully deactivate\n"
"This embedded instance so it will never turn on again")   
exit_msg = '**Leaving Nested interpreter'

# Wrap it in a function that gives me more context:
def ipsh():
    ipshell = InteractiveShellEmbed(config=cfg, banner1=banner_msg, exit_msg=exit_msg)

    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    msg   = 'Stopped at {0.f_code.co_filename} at line {0.f_lineno}'.format(frame)

    # Go back one level! 
    # This is needed because the call to ipshell is inside the function ipsh()
    ipshell(msg,stack_depth=2)
```

Then, whenever I want to debug something in my code, I place `ipsh()` right at the location where I need to do object inspection, etc. For example, say I want to debug `my_function` below

#### Using it:

```
def my_function(b):
  a = b
  ipsh() # <- This will embed a full-fledged IPython interpreter
  a = 4
```

and then I invoke `my_function(2)` in one of the following ways:

1. Either by running a Python program that invokes this function from a Unix shell
2. Or by invoking it directly from IPython

Regardless of how I invoke it, the interpreter stops at the line that says `ipsh()`. Once you are done, you can do `Ctrl-D` and Python will resume execution (with any variable updates that you made). Note that, if you run the code from a regular IPython  the IPython shell (case 2 above), the new IPython shell will be **nested** inside the one from which you invoked it, which is perfectly fine, but it's good to be aware of. Eitherway, once the interpreter stops on the location of `ipsh`, I can inspect the value of `a` (which be `2`), see what functions and objects are defined, etc.

#### The problem:

The solution above can be used to have Python stop anywhere you want in your code, and then drop you into  a fully-fledged IPython interpreter. Unfortunately it does not let you add or remove breakpoints once you invoke the script, which is highly frustrating. In my opinion, this is the **only** thing that is preventing IPython from becoming a great debugging tool for Python.

#### The best you can do for now:

A workaround is to place `ipsh()` a priori at the different locations where you want the Python interpreter to launch an IPython shell (i.e. a `breakpoint`). You can then "jump" between different pre-defined, hard-coded "breakpoints" with `Ctrl-D`, which would exit the current embedded IPython shell and stop again whenever the interpreter hits the next call to `ipsh()`.

If you go this route, one way to exit  "debugging mode" and ignore all subsequent breakpoints, is to use `ipshell.dummy_mode = True` which will make Python ignore any subsequent instantiations of the `ipshell` object that we created above.

Comment: Please update this whenever you find an even better solution. But this looks great. I will use it.

Comment: where do we use `ipshell.dummy_mode = True`? Can we use it from with in an ongoing ipython session?

Comment: @Phani -- yes, you can do this anytime during the "debugging session" (i.e. whenever the nested shell `ipsh()` is invoked and you are done with debugging).

Comment: but it says that it cannot find `ipshell` variable.

Comment: Where/how do you define/import cfg, banner_msg, exit_msg, and inspect?

Comment: @GordonBean I found the context in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669186/using-ipython-as-an-effective-debugger

Comment: This seems to work well for me: https://github.com/kdodia/snippets/blob/master/ipsh.py

Comment: I needed to add `import inspect` before it worked. The command line customization seems to be broken for me though.

Comment: Thanks @tuner That's correct. I have fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Why not just using `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`? Maybe I miss something, but I don't see the advantage of your much more complicated method.

Comment: @luator I think that the difference is that this method allows you to use iPython right at the breakpoint and execute any Python command. `ipdb.set_trace` only gives access to the `ipdb` commands

Comment: @BerkU. I *can* execute any Python command with `ipdb.set_trace`. At least I never noticed any restrictions and I use it quite a lot.

Comment: When I use this method and write this code: ```a = 3; cap = [a for x in range(1)]``` the interpreter outputs: ```NameError: name 'a' is not defined```.
I have no idea why.

Comment: @LucasAlonso I had the same problem myself with embedded shells. I think there are some tickets about this problem in IPython (BTW, see my latest update on this answer).

Answer (score 19):

You can start IPython session from [pudb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) and go back to the debugging session as you like.

BTW, ipdb is using IPython behind the scenes and you can actually use IPython functionality such as TAB completion and magic commands (the one starts with `%`).  If you are OK with ipdb you can start it from IPython using commands such as `%run` and `%debug`.  ipdb session is actually better than plain IPython one in the sense you can go up and down in the stack trace etc.  What is missing in ipdb for "object inspection"?

Also, python.el bundled with Emacs >= 24.3 has nice ipdb support.

Comment: Thanks tkf. I am big fan of your Emacs-Jedi package. When you said that Emacs 24.3 has nice support for ipdb, would you mind elaborating? I usually start IPython in a separate `M-x ansi-term` buffer, and then I use [isend-mode](https://github.com/emacsmirror/isend-mode) to bind my source buffers to the  IPython buffer so that I can send code to the IPython interpreter with a keyboard shortcut that automatically sends the `%paste` magic to the IPython buffer. This allows me to quickly test regions in IPython. I always run my programs from this IPython shell with `run` and use `embed()` to stop.

Comment: For example, when you step through code, the source code is opened in the other buffer with arrow pointing the current execution point.  You also have send-region command, like you do with isend-mode.

Comment: Thanks @tkf How can I start an `ipdb` debugging session using `python.el` and have things like `send-region` etc. to the corresponding shell? In general, where can I find more info on this?

Comment: I use `%run` or `%debug`.  I guess `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` works too.  I don't think you can send multiple lines to ipdb.  That's ipdb's limitation.  But probably `%paste` trick works.  You may want to send a feature request to IPython dev.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like the approach in @gaborous's answer [is deprecated](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9731/).

The new approach seems to be:

```
from IPython.core import debugger
debug = debugger.Pdb().set_trace

def buggy_method():
    debug()
```

Comment: Does this allow you to use `ipdb` statements within ipython shell, while debugging?

Answer (score 8):

You can start `IPython` *from within* `ipdb`.

Induce the `ipdb` debugger<sup>1</sup>:

```py
import idpb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

Enter IPython *from within* in the `ipdb>` console<sup>2</sup>:

```py
from IPython import embed; embed()
```

Return to the `ipdb>` console from within `IPython`:

```py
exit
```

---

If you're lucky enough to be using Emacs, things can be made even more convenient.

This requires using `M-x shell`.  Using [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) and [bm](https://github.com/joodland/bm), define the following snippet.  This will replace the text `ipdb` in the editor with the `set-trace` line.  After inserting the snippet, the line will be highlighted so that it is easily noticeable and navigable.  Use `M-x bm-next` to navigate.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: ipdb
# key: ipdb
# expand-env: ((yas-after-exit-snippet-hook #'bm-toggle))
# --
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

---

<sup>1</sup> All on one line for easy deletion.  Since `imports` only happen once, this form ensures `ipdb` will be imported when you need it with no extra overhead.

<sup>2</sup> You can save yourself some typing by importing `IPython` [within your `.pdbrc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53227452/5065796):

```py
try:
    from IPython import embed
except:
    pass
```

This allows you to simply call `embed()` from within `ipdb` (of course, only when IPython is installed).

Answer (score 7):

Prefixing an "!" symbol to commands you type in pdb seems to have the same effect as doing something in an IPython shell. This works for accessing help for a certain function, or even variable names. Maybe this will help you to some extent. For example,

```
ipdb> help(numpy.transpose)
*** No help on (numpy.transpose)
```

But !help(numpy.transpose) will give you the expected help page on numpy.transpose. Similarly for variable names, say you have a variable l, typing "l" in pdb lists the code, but !l prints the value of l.

Comment: This is a nasty pdb gotcha, and well worth knowing about.

Answer (score 5):

the right, easy, cool, exact answer for the question is to use %run macro with -d flag.

```
In [4]: run -d myscript.py
NOTE: Enter 'c' at the ipdb>  prompt to continue execution.        
> /cygdrive/c/Users/mycodefolder/myscript.py(4)<module>()
      2                                                            
      3                        
----> 4 a=1                                            
      5 b=2
```

Comment: This should be higher up. If I need to insert a line into my code (within a module) I need to restart IPython to reload the module. WIth this, I can just `%save /tmp/foo.py x-y` The code I want to run and debug and then `%run -d /tmp/foo.py` to set the breakpoint wherever I like. Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [this tip](http://vjethava.blogspot.fr/2010/11/matlabs-keyboard-command-in-python.html)?

> Or better still, use ipython, and call:
>
> ```
> from IPython.Debugger import Tracer; debug_here = Tracer()
> ```
>
> then you can just use
>
> ```
> debug_here()
> ```
>
> whenever you want to set a breakpoint

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython.Debugger'`

Comment: @JohnGreene This is a very old answer, nowadays IPython has been renamed to Jupyter and the API changed a lot.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use an IDE like [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) which should allow you to interact with your code while debugging (using an IPython console, in fact). In fact, Spyder is very MATLAB-like, which I presume was intentional. That includes variable inspectors, variable editing, built-in access to documentation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you type exit() in embed() console the code continue and go to the next embed() line.

Answer (score 2):

The [Pyzo](http://www.pyzo.org/) IDE has similar capabilities as the OP asked for. You don't have to start in debug mode. Similarly to MATLAB, the commands are executed in the shell. When you set up a break-point in some source code line, the IDE stops the execution there and you can debug and issue regular IPython commands as well.

It does seem however that step-into doesn't (yet?) work well (i.e. stopping in one line and then stepping into another function) unless you set up another break-point.

Still, coming from MATLAB, this seems the best solution I've found.

Answer (score 2):

From python 3.2, you have the `interact` command, which gives you access to the full python/ipython command space.

Answer (score 2):

## Developing New Code

*Debugging inside IPython*

1. Use Jupyter/IPython cell execution to speed up experiment iterations
2. Use %%debug for step through

Cell Example:

```
%%debug
...: for n in range(4):
...:    n>2
```

## Debugging Existing Code

*IPython inside debugging*

1. Debugging a broken unit test: `pytest ... --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:TerminalPdb --pdb`
2. Debugging outside of test case: `breakpoint()`, `python -m ipdb`, etc.
3. IPython.embed() for full IPython functionality where needed while in the debugger

## Thoughts on Python

I agree with the OP that many things MATLAB does nicely Python still does not have and really should since just about everything in the language favors development speed over production speed. Maybe someday I will contribute more than trivial bug fixes to CPython.

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/f042f3fea7560afcb518a1940daa46a72fbcfa68

See also [Is it possible to run commands in IPython with debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689378/is-it-possible-to-run-commands-in-ipython-with-debugging/46333421#46333421)

Comment: It was really useful to use `IPython.terminal.debugger:TerminalPdb` instead of `IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb`.  It makes IPython and ipdb much more interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Running from inside Emacs' IPython-shell and breakpoint set via pdb.set_trace() should work.

Checked with python-mode.el, M-x ipython RET etc.

Answer (score 0):

If put `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` at cell outside function, it will occur error.

Using `%pdb` or `%debug`, you can only see the filnal error result. You cannot see the code doing step by step.

I use following skill:

```
%%writefile temp.py
.....cell code.....
```

save the code of cell to file **temp.py**.

and then
`%run -i -d temp.py`, it will run the cell code by pdb .

`-i`: run the file in IPython’s namespace instead of an empty one.

`-d`: run your program under the control of pdb, the Python debugger.