# IPython embed breakpoint - How can I see the code around the breakpoint?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython, pry

Say I've got some python code with an `embed` breakpoint like so:

```
from IPython import embed

def my_func(self):
  some_var = 'awesome sauce'
  embed()
  # other stuff happens
```

when I run my test runner... with say `pytest`:

```
$ python -m pytest -k test_something_awesome
```

How can my ipython terminal give me the contextual code around my embed breakpoint?

So instead of:

[image]

I would get something similar to ruby's PRY output like:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like [`ipdb.set_trace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894963/2357112) would be more appropriate than `IPython.embed`.

Comment: this does in fact work better. thank you sir.