# setting a custom option in ipython session

Tags: python, python-3.x

In R, I very frequently set session options to control program flow. For example, if I want my script to run in debug mode i can do `options(debug = T)` and then check for it in my script with `getOption("debug", F)`. Does python have anything equivalent?

Note this is not the same as passing an argument to my script as I want to not touch the code after starting debugging.

Comment: Have you looked for answers to this question?  What did you find?  For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867347/step-by-step-debugging-with-ipython) is some information all about debugging with IPython.

Comment: yes - i have found nothing other than setting environment variables. also, this question has nothing to do with debugging, that was simply an example of where this mechanism is useful

Comment: Oh okay.  When I googled 'ipython options' I got this result: [Docs » Configuration and customization » IPython options](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/index.html?highlight=options) It contains a list of the options available in different types of IPython environments.  There are also [magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) Do any of these look like the options you are looking for?  If not what other types of options are you looking for?

Comment: yes, i've seen this as well. i'm looking to set a custom defined option. `debug` is not a built in option into R, it is like an environment variable that is local to that specific R session.

Comment: Sounds like you mean user-defined settings for your script. Check out [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).  That's all I can think of.  Or you could simply pass a variable as a function argument e.g. `def myfunc(debug=False)` and then call it with `myfunc(debug=True)` when you need that.

Comment: One thing about Python I think is that most things are explicit.  As far as I'm aware you can't (or shouldn't) write a script that has behaviour dependent on some invisible environment setting.

Comment: Also, you might be interested in [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)

Comment: ok sounds good, i'll check that out. thanks for your help.

Comment: Always happy to help an R convert.  Feel free to upvote any comments that were helpful...